# The user and owner objects appear to be optional in the question timeline result.

Tags: bug, status-deferred, documentation

This is probably just a simple documentation fix and not really a bug.  The doc for the /questions/{id}/timeline method says that the `user` and `owner` objects are **not** optional, but they aren't always present in the results.

Example:
http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions/2938604/timeline

API Help:
http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=questions/{id}/timeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically that's incorrect.

The help docs say nothing about the required/optional nature of `user` and `owner`, only whether certain of their subfields are required should they be present.  This is a gap in our automagic doc generation system which will - eventually - be fixed.

When it is, `user` and `owner` will be marked "optional."

Comment: D'oh!  You're right.  My eye skipped into the `user_id` field because I was only looking for one specific attribute.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Did you really make an "automagic" doc generation system? Neat!

Comment: @George - the majority of the /help information is generated in code.  We did this so its *harder* (though, obviously not impossible) for the docs and the code to get out of sync.